# Why <li> tags are misplaced?

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists

There is a table with four columns. In the first column there is an image. I have set the `align attribute` to `top`. The rest of the columns contain texts. But the `<li>` tags lose the `inline display` order when the text is inserted in the fourth column.

Any suggestions to solve this problem will be highly appreciated.

```css
ul.film1 li,
ul.film2 li,
ul.film3 li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 290px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
#tableheadheader1,
#tableheadbody1 {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
#tableheadfooter1 {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<ul class="film1">
  <li id="tableheadimage1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" align="top">
  </li>
  <li id="tableheadheader1">
    <p>Tomorrowland</p>
  </li>
  <li id="tableheadbody1">
    <p>2015</p>
  </li>
  <li id="tableheadfooter1">
    <p>Whenever Casey Newton (Britt Robertson) touches a lapel pin with the letter T on it, she finds herself transported to Tomorrowland, a city filled with huge robots and sleek buildings. The gifted young woman recruits the help of scientist Frank Walker
      (George Clooney), a previous visitor to Tomorrowland, who years ago made a startling discovery about the future. Together, the two adventurers travel to the metropolis to uncover its mysterious secrets.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `vertical-align: top;` on your `<li>` elements should fix your problem.

```css
ul.film1 li,
ul.film2 li,
ul.film3 li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 290px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /* <-- this has been added */
}
#tableheadheader1,
#tableheadbody1 {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
#tableheadfooter1 {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<ul class="film1">
  <li id="tableheadimage1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" align="top">
  </li>
  <li id="tableheadheader1">
    <p>Tomorrowland</p>
  </li>
  <li id="tableheadbody1">
    <p>2015</p>
  </li>
  <li id="tableheadfooter1">
    <p>Whenever Casey Newton (Britt Robertson) touches a lapel pin with the letter T on it, she finds herself transported to Tomorrowland, a city filled with huge robots and sleek buildings. The gifted young woman recruits the help of scientist Frank Walker
      (George Clooney), a previous visitor to Tomorrowland, who years ago made a startling discovery about the future. Together, the two adventurers travel to the metropolis to uncover its mysterious secrets.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```